# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Route Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Thi is my RouteConfig class

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "pagamento_riuscito",
            url: "pagamento_riuscito",
            defaults: new { controller = "Pagamento", action = "Pagamento_Riuscito" }

        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

But when i go to the url local ~/pagamento_riuscito
the page returned is Errore server nell'applicazione '/'.

Impossibile trovare la risorsa.

Descrizione: HTTP 404. La risorsa che si sta cercando (o una delle sue dipendenze) potrebbe essere stata rimossa, rinominata o non essere temporaneamente disponibile. Verificare che l'URL riportato di seguito sia stato digitato correttamente.

URL richiesto: /pagamento_riuscito

This is my PagamentoController

```
    public class PagamentoController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Pagamento/
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void Index(FormCollection forms)
    {
        ...

    }



    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Pagamento_Riuscito()
    {
        BeanOrder bean = new BeanOrder();
        bean = (BeanOrder)Session["beanOrdine"];
        if (bean.TipoPagamento.Equals("creditcard"))
        {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = Request.Params;

            String result = parameters.Get("result");
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result.Equals("APPROVED"))
                {

                }
            }
        }


        return View();
    }
}
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you add the attribute `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` you can 't *go to the url local ~/pagamento_riuscito* . Try removing this attribute to accept Get verb.